# GAL from outlook with exchange from which one to get?

Tags: c#, email, outlook

I'm currently writing an interface to outlook and thus I'm trying to access the GAL.The problem I currently have is quite basic I guess. I can get the list of addresses in the GAL but they have no contact item in them. When I print the Type of the address entries I always get "EX" which I guess stands for exchange. Now my question is: If I want to get the eMails instead of only the displayed address entry name do I have to do so by connecting directly to the exchange server? Or can I do so with the interop outlook methods?

Below is the code I use to get the gal from outlook:

```
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application oApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
            AddressList gal = oApp.Session.GetGlobalAddressList();
            foreach (AddressEntry entry in gal.AddressEntries)
            {
                String addString = entry.Name + ": ";
                if (entry.GetContact() != null)
                {
                    addString += entry.GetContact().FirstName + " " + entry.GetContact().LastName + ": " + entry.GetContact().Email1Address;
                    dataGlobal.Add("CONTACT: " + addString);

                }
                else
                {

                    addString += entry.Type;
                    dataGlobal.Add(addString);
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GetContact only works for the IPM.Note items (represented by the ContactItem objects) in one of your Contacts folders.

In case of EX entries, use [AddressEntry.GetExchangeUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb175075(v=office.12).aspx) and use the [ExchangeUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb176658(v=office.12).aspx) object.

To read the PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES, use AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty and pass the appropriate DASL name `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F".`

Comment: Interesting had overlooked that. is there also a way to get not only the primary smtp address of the user but also the proxies / alias mail addresses (thus: msExchShadowProxyAddresses, proxyAddresses as they are called from AD)?

Comment: Sure, the property you want is PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES (DASL name is     http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F). You can access it using AddressEntry.PorpertyAccessor.GetProperty. Take a look at the GAL objects in OutlookSpy (click IAddrbook or IMAPISession | QueryIdentity etc.)

Comment: hmmm tried to use that property:
 var ProxyAddr = entry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty("PR_EMS_AB_PROXY_ADDRESSES"); gives me an exception: Property cannot be analyzed or has no valid format (translated from my motherlanguage into english)

Comment: You need to pass the DASL property name - see the updated reply above. Take a look at the GAL objects using OutlookSpy. It will show you all available properties and their DASL names.

Comment: http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x800F101F <-- when I try to take a look: "The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: It is not a url. It is a DASL property name (string). That string (see the updated answer above, did you look at the property in OutlookSpy?) is what you need to pass to GetProperty.

Comment: ah ok that was a misunderstanding there. (tnx will try it out as soon as I'm back at work)

Comment: works quite fine that way (getting me all types of proxy addresses) tnx