# Microsoft Exchange / Active Directory properties for mails to be used to read a GAL

Tags: c#, email, active-directory, outlook, exchange-server

I'm currently creating an application which is using outlook as well as the exchange server / active directory in my company to create mails (I've had a few other questions here thus already).

I'm currently trying to read the GAL for it to be used when sending mails over my application. From the solutions I've seen so far it seems  to me that the variant where I read the mail addresses from the active directory instead of connecting to the exchange server (I first tried outlook but aside from getting only the account names with the type "EX" thus that they are stored on the exchange server I didn't get much info there).

What I've done so far is gtting access to teh active directory and reading all users from there

```
       DirectorySearcher objsearch = new DirectorySearcher();
        String strrootdse = objsearch.SearchRoot.Path;
        DirectoryEntry objdirentry = new DirectoryEntry(strrootdse);
        objsearch.Filter = "(& (mailnickname=*)(objectClass=user))";
        objsearch.SearchScope = System.DirectoryServices.SearchScope.Subtree;
        objsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
        objsearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("mail");
        objsearch.PropertyNamesOnly = true;
        objsearch.Sort.Direction = System.DirectoryServices.SortDirection.Ascending;
        objsearch.Sort.PropertyName = "cn";
        SearchResultCollection colresults = objsearch.FindAll();
        List<String> arrGal = new List<String>();
        foreach (SearchResult objresult in colresults)
        {
            arrGal.Add(objresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["cn"].Value + ": " + objresult.GetDirectoryEntry().Properties["mail"].Value);
            }
```

Now after looking at the active directory I saw that there are also proxies and that (at least at my company) the "mail" property is not necessarily one of the mail addresses listed in the proxies.

Thus I found these two attributes: msExchShadowProxyAddresses, proxyAddresses

From what I've seen so far from them by looking at samples they look like they are identical, but even searching I didn't find anything on the web so far there.

Thus my Question when I'm trying to get the GAL from active directory Can I use both of these properties (thus they are always identical) or should I only use the ShadowProxy property or is there something I need to take into special consideration there?

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to AD instead of the Outlook Object Model. What is exactly that you cannot retrieve using OOM?

Comment: I tried to use the outlook interops functionality first. But regardless what I did I never got the mails of the items in the GAL instead only the "name" of the item and in addition to that the info that it comes from exchange server (type: "EX"). I would have REALLY liked it if I weere able to get teh mailadresses (including proxy mail addresses) with the outlook interops but seemingly wasn't possible (as others used a similar code and it funtioned I guess how the exchange+AD is conffigured here (which I cannot affect) is the reason for it not working from that direction.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use AddressEntry.GetExchangeuser method. See my reply to your other post.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24926728/gal-from-outlook-with-exchange-from-which-one-to-get  is an alternative there to using AD yes (a very nice working one, which is also the one I'm going to use tnx again there). Although in the current question here it was more about what properties would be correct to use if one uses the AD way.